# Множественный вызов AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть событие при котором отсылается ajax запрос. Проблема в том, что при событии наведения - AJAX посылается несколько раз, почему так?

```
$(".user_info_pop").on("mouseover", function () {

var el = $(this);
var  data = $(this).attr('data');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/user/getUser',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {id : data},

  success: function(result){
    $('.popover').hide();
    if (result.user_info[0].DetailToUsersPhoto == null ) { 
            var photo = '/public/images/notphoto.jpg'; }
        else { var photo = result.user_info[0].DetailToUsersPhoto;}

    el.popover({ 
        content: parseTpl(pop_user_info, {
                                'spec': result.progress,
                                'exp': result.user_info[0].DetailToUsersExpirience,
                                'id_user': result.user_info[0].idUsers,
                                'name': result.user_info[0].DetailToUsersName,
                                'site' : result.user_info[0].DetailToUsersSite,
                                'tw' : result.user_info[0].DetailToUsersTW,
                                'youtube' : result.user_info[0].DetailToUsersYTB,
                                'fb' : result.user_info[0].DetailToUsersFB,
                                'photo' : photo,
                                'country' : result.user_info[0].CountryName,
                                'city' : result.user_info[0].CityName,
                                'questions' : result.statistic[0].CNT,
                                'points' : result.statistic[1].CNT,
                                'answers' : result.statistic[2].CNT,

                            }), 
        placement: 'top', 
        html: true, 
        delay: { show: 100, hide: 4000 },
        trigger: 'hover' 
    }).popover("show");
  }
});
return false;
```

});

И второй очень важный вопрос, можно ли второй раз не вызывать AJAX, а сохранить вернувшийся результат от AJAX, чтобы при повторном mouseover - не делать запроса и вытянуть сохраненные данные?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то повторную отправку вызывает ваш триггер - **trigger: 'hover'**. А вот по второму вопросу - я бы однозначно сохранил в Local Storage.

Comment: а кто мешает сделать глобальную переменную и туда вносить данные обработки ответа после первого запроса, и потом проверять, если переменная не пустая, то возвращать ее данные, если пустая - делать запрос AJAX.

Comment: не нужно вешать аякс-запросы на маусовер, это быдлокодерство